# setState reloads old value after value change

Tags: android, flutter, dart, setstate

I have a problem with flutter:
Here's my build method for filling TextFields from DB and SendValue method for sending edited values to DB.
After setState TextFields shows old values for a second and then loads the edited values.
This happens after server answer that values had been changed.
What`s the reason of reloading old values?

```
return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Editing values'),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          child: FutureBuilder<List<Photo>>(
            future: fetchPhotos(http.Client(), args.id),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {

              if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

              return snapshot.hasData
                  ? Fields(snapshot.data)
                  : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            },
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 30, 30, 30),
        ),
      );


Future SendValues(String id) async {

      http.Client client;
      client = http.Client();
      var uri = new Uri.http('localhost', 'edituser.php');
      final response =
      await client.post(uri, body: {

        'id': id,
        'name': contname.text,
        'surname': contsurname.text,

      },
        );

      if  (response.body.contains('OK')) 

       setState(() {
       });
       else 
       print('error');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It shows old value because `setState` is being called after the http request is done, which takes a while.

Don't wait for the response:

```dart
Future SendValues(String id) async {
  http.Client client;
  client = http.Client();
  var uri = new Uri.http('localhost', 'edituser.php');
  final response = client.post(
    uri,
    body: {'id': id, 'name': contname.text, 'surname': contsurname.text},
  );

  setState(() {});
  return response;
}
```

Comment: Still the same, reloads old value, then loads new

Comment: could you show how are you calling `SendValues`?

Comment: `   RaisedButton(

            splashColor: Theme
                .of(context)
                .primaryColor,
            highlightColor: Theme
                .of(context)
                .primaryColor,
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
            child: Text(
              'Save',
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20),),

           onPressed: () {


             SendValues(photos.first.id);


           }

          ), `

Comment: you're not using the returned value from `SendValues`, make sure that your `FutureBuilder` uses it